# How to verify if two cells are equal and, if not, make an empty row above and move on?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a vba code to check each cell in two sheets if they are equal. If not, create an empty row above and move on for both of the sheets.

I don't have much experience using Vba so I'm a little confused. I hope you've understood my problem and a appreciate since now.

```
Private Sub compare_cells(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target Is Nothing Then Next
    If Cells(Target.Row, 1).Value = 'another row ' Cells(Target.Row, 4).Value Then
        Next
    Else
        'inset empty row above of the sheet with the missing value
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

The code above is really ugly, that's why I need help. The data seems like this:
sheet 1:
[image: as being sheet 1]

sheet 2:
[image: as being sheet 2]

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54657438/edit) to include the code you have so far. Some sample data and the expected result would also be useful. Among other things, it's not clear where you want the empty row above, (i.e. above the cells in both sheets, or in just one of the sheets?). It's also no clear what happens if two pairs of cells on the same row match, will two empty rows end up being inserted or should it be just one?

Comment: i hope you can understand my issue now.

Comment: Please don't _only_ post images of data, post it as text, and if you feel it adds value you can post an image too - as it is you are requiring someone to retype the data if they want to test some code.  Also, please post the "after" version of the data too, ie how you want the sample to end up after the code has run.

Comment: *"I'm trying to make a vba code to check each cell in two sheets if they are equal. If not, create an empty row above and move on for both of the sheets"* - I'm not following. Please show a before and after example. In both of your pictures, I don't see any new row inserted anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct in your question above... You want to produce an empty row, above ANY values that DO NOT match between two worksheets.

Based on this, and the above code, you are not too FAR off the right track.

Try the below code...

```
Private Sub compare_cells(ByVal Target1 As Range, ByVal Target2 As Range)
If Target1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If Target2 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Sheets(Target1.Parent.Name)
Set ws2 = Sheets(Target2.Parent.Name)
    If Target1.Value <> Target2.Value Then
        ' If they don't match place your code here
        ws1.Range(Target1.Row & ":" & Target1.Row).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        ws2.Range(Target2.Row & ":" & Target2.Row).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    End If

End Sub
```

You can call this by using this within another macro...

`Call compare_cells(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"), Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D1"))`

If you use the above macro, then this will compare Range "A1" on Sheet1, with Range "D1" on Sheet 2. If these two cells do not match, then it will insert a row above both A1, and D1.